# Generating huge text with blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

How can I create text in Minecraft? I don't want to build it by hand so I'm looking for a Generator. Is there any way to put it directly in the world or to generate a schematic or something?

Minecraft Version: 1.9

[image]

It's not very beautiful but that's basically how it should look like.

Comment: And you want it strictly made with blocks? What about some holographic displays that are in MC nowadays ? (Like /title or some plugins making those holographic displays)

Comment: I don't want /title. But right, i remember those text displays. May be an option. Thx.

Comment: How about an MCEdit filter? I think there might be one out there.

Comment: I looked at MineTEXT but i didn't work. I think it's outdated ):

Comment: I might go write one....

Comment: refer to [this](http://static.planetminecraft.com/files/resource_media/screenshot/1145/oie_105317G258JpXo_799312.jpg)

Comment: I think i'm gonna write a plugin. Litte bit more interactive (:

Comment: @epicTCK in the jar of minecraft you can find the letters in assets\minecraft\textures\font\ascii.png. Well structured (ASCII).

Comment: Just read @epicTCK's ascii textures with Java and where it's black paint a block and where it's not don't.

Comment: Ok i did so and created a plugin :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I could not find any plugin or McEdit filter so I created my own plugin which works very good!

More info: https://github.com/simonmeusel/Textup